# How to pull data from API and store it in HDFS

Tags: hdfs, etl

I am aware of flume and Kafka but these are event driven tools. I don't need it to be event driven or real time but may be just schedule the import once in a day.

What are the data ingestion tools available for importing data from API's in HDFS?

I am not using HBase either but HDFS and Hive.

I have used `R` language for that for quite a time but I am looking for a more robust,may be native solution to Hadoop environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into using Scala or Python for this. There are a couple ways to approach pulling from an API into HDFS. The first approach would be to write a script which runs on your edge node(essentially just a linux server) and pulls data from the API and lands it in a directory on the linux file system. Then your script can use HDFS file system commands to put the data into HDFS.

The second approach would be to use Scala or Python with Spark to call the API and directly load the data into HDFS using a Spark submit job. Again this script would be run from an edge node it is just utilizing Spark to bypass having to land the data in the LFS.

The first option is easier to implement. The second option is worth looking into if you have huge data volumes or an API that could be parallelized by making calls to muliple IDs/accounts at once.

Comment: If I just a python script for this and store the data in text file, how do  I update the data in case of changes? I usually convert JSON to CSV and then map it to hive. Updating a row in CSV is much of a problem.How to approach this problem?

Comment: I would just replace the entire CSV file each time or only pull new/updated data from the API and then update your target Hive table with insert overwrite statements which would allow you to keep your historical data in the table and only update/add records as needed.

Comment: Oh, that sounds cool. Is that possible? How to update rows in Hive with new values using a programming language like Python or R? I have tried replacing the CSV files but it just does not feel good.

Comment: you would need to execute a Hive SQL statement through your script which would use an insert overwrite to load data. This would work well if your table was partitioned for keeping the historical data and then adding new data to new partitions. you should read up on how hive tables can be loaded and put together the pieces of how to meet your needs.